# Unable to update Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I can't update Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10.

After a while, the installation rolls back and Windows 7 starts again with the message:

```
0x8007001F - 0x20006 the update failed to install during the SAFE_OS phase
             with an error during the REPLICATE_OC operator
```

- Microsoft Update Troubleshooter gives the following:

  ```
  Windows Update Error 0x80073712 **Not Corrected**
  ```
- I ran `sfc /scannow`, but no integrity violations were found, uninstalled antivirus, and ran the System Update Readiness tool, which points to 2 missing files:

  ```
  servicing\packages\Package_152_for_KB3022345~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.mum
  servicing\packages\Package_152_for_KB3022345~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.cat
  ```

  (Other files were missing at first, but I was able to find them on another computer.)

I can't uninstall, or remove, the KB3022345 upgrade using the following, receiving error `0x800f0900`:

```bat
wusa /Uninstall /Kb:3022345

dism /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:<name>
```

I've also run SFCFix and tweaking.com's Windows Repair with no results; at first, Windows 7 could not install updates, but now all W7 updates have been installed.

Comment: To what Windows version are you upgrading exactly? Why not upgrade to Windows 10 (it's still free)?

Comment: sorry, my bad I'm updating to W10

Comment: Which version of Windows 10? Is there a reason not to do a clean installation of it instead of upgrading Windows 7?

Comment: Use Upgrade assistant 1803 strictly, and do not allow it to upgrade self or download and use more recent version. After upgrade use Upgrade assistant 1909, then Microsoft update.

Comment: Where do you get this upgrade assistant that works in windows 7?

Comment: @harrymc I'll do any version that works - upgrading does not work and I need to keep the files and softwares

Comment: @Moab the media creation tool from microsoft

Comment: @Pimpoum That just creates the media, how does it assist with problems like this? Its not called that anywhere on the internet, there is one if you have W10 already installed, helps upgrade to the next release.

Comment: @Moab no it says on the tool's page that it can be used to upgrage from Windows XP, Vista or 7

Comment: @Akina, just tried with a 1803 iso but the problem remains the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

I got some help from the user softwaremaniac at Sysnative forums - he basically helped me remove any reference in the registry to the KB3022345 with the Farbar Recovery Scan Tool.

This KB is not needed any more for Win10 upgrade. If it can't removed by `wusa`, it can be done by some registry trickery. After that, the Win10 upgrade will be possible again.

[Here is the post](https://www.sysnative.com/forums/threads/windows-seven-cant-update.30365/)

Well basically the problem was that the files of KB3022345 were corrupt. and althoug Win10 does not need this KB, it Win7 wouldn't update to Win10 because of the corruption (and the corruption prevented me also to uninstall the bad KB).

So with Farbar Recovery Scan Tool i did a registry search of "KB3022345" and the user at sysnative forum made me a script to delete all the references to the KB.

W10 is on now.

Comment: Ok, but how does it answer the question on the top?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica : not sure to understand your question: I can now update to W10 because the KB is not required anymore

Comment: Ok, maybe I understand your question better. So, the logic is that you effectively uninstall (or try to uninstall) this KB by registry edits, and then install it again (or, yet better: not install it anyhow). It is trivial for you, but not for the people reading your answer. I suggest to give more details. (Not I was the downvoter, I give you now an up and a minor improvement edit).

Comment: Hey there, I was the downvoter when I reviewed this on the LQ queue. Your answer in the initial form was lacking everything and you got an answer because someone else looked at a log of a script they probably created for you to execute. Now that you included more details and effectively how to fix the problem, I removed the DV and replaced it with a upvote. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution would be to do a clean installation of Windows 10, rather
than an in-place upgrade from Windows 7.

However, if you would like to keep as many settings as possible from Windows 7,
so would like to do a gentle in-place upgrade, and as the problems seem to be
with your Windows 7 setup, I would suggest doing it in two steps:

1. [Perform an In-Place Upgrade on Windows 7 to Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2255099/how-to-perform-an-in-place-upgrade-on-windows-vista-windows-7-windows)
   using a boot media that is on the same Service Pack level.
   This may fix the problems you are having with missing files, without the doubtful
   practices of copying them from other computers.
2. Perform an In-Place Upgrade on Windows 7 to Windows 10
   which might now succeed without these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Vijay_Verma's answer at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-update-keeps-failing-0x8007001f-0x20006/5797cde4-6996-4359-bea4-644e9c22f48d suggests to delete/rename away these files/folders:

- C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\
- C:\Windows\System32\catroot2\
- C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.Log

It suggests the `wuauserv`/`CryptSvc`/`BITS`/`msiserver` services will need to be stopped while you remove the folders.

And for CBS.log, the Windows Modules Installer service (`TrustedInstaller`) needs to be stopped, possibly requiring setting the Startup Type to Manual and rebooting.