# SAFE_OS, REPLICATE_OC errors upgrading Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've discovered that a PC is running Windows 10 Pro version 1709 which has been out of support since 2019/04/09 so I'm trying to upgrade it but it keeps failing.

Attempting up upgrade via Windows Update fails with error `A current driver on your PC may be better than the driver we're trying to install. We'll keep trying to install.`.

Attempting to upgrade via installation media fails with the following errors:

```
0x8007001F - 0x20006
The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during REPLICATE_OC operation
```

[image]

Thus far, I have tried everything that I can find online and more:

1. Ensured that the system drive has sufficient storage space available.
2. Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter as admin which reportedly found and fixed the following problems:

   - `Potential Windows Update Database error detected`
   - `Windows Update components must be repaired`
   - `Check for pending updates`
3. Run the following commands as admin:
   3a. `net stop wuauserv`
   3b. `net stop bits`
   3c. `ren c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old`
   3d. `net start wuauserv`
   3e. `net stop bits`
4. Stopped the Windows service `cryptsvc`, moved all files from `%systemroot%\system32\catroot2\` to `%systemroot%\system32\catroot2.old`, and re-started the service.
5. `.old`-ed the folder `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\`.
6. Deleted the folder `C:\Windows10Upgrade\` and re-run the Windows 10 Update Assistant.
7. Run the command `sfc /scannow` as admin which reported no problems:

   ```
   Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

   Beginning verification phase of system scan.
   Verification 100% complete.

   Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
   ```
8. Run the command `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` as admin which reported no problems:

   ```
   Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
   Version: 10.0.16299.15

   Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

   [==========================100.0%==========================] No component store corruption detected.
   The operation completed successfully.
   ```
9. Run the command `DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` as admin which reported no problems:

   ```
   Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
   Version: 10.0.16299.15

   Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

   [==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
   The operation completed successfully.
   ```
10. Run the command `chkdsk /scan` as admin which reported no problems:

    ```
    The type of the file system is NTFS.

    Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
      2055168 file records processed.
    File verification completed.
      12866 large file records processed.
      0 bad file records processed.

    Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
      26874 reparse records processed.
      2699910 index entries processed.
    Index verification completed.
      0 unindexed files scanned.
      0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
      26874 reparse records processed.

    Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
    Security descriptor verification completed.
      322372 data files processed.
    CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
    Usn Journal verification completed.

    Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
    No further action is required.

    233916415 KB total disk space.
    185713784 KB in 1632128 files.
        724380 KB in 322373 indexes.
             0 KB in bad sectors.
       2138943 KB in use by the system.
         65536 KB occupied by the log file.
      45339308 KB available on disk.

          4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
      58479103 total allocation units on disk.
      11334827 allocation units available on disk.
    ```
11. Downloaded an official ISO of Windows 10 v1909 64-bit, mounted it, and run `setup.exe`.
12. Downloaded an official ISO of Windows 10 v1903 64-bit, mounted it, and run `setup.exe`.
13. Found that device drivers were up to date.
14. Updated the BIOS firmware to the latest version.
15. Used the method documented at https://errortools.com/windows/how-to-fix-safe_os-phase-error-during-replicate_oc-operation-error-in-windows-10/ to remove the files `\Windows\System32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll` from the installation media.

I've now run out of ideas, out-of-band management isn't available, and physical access is risky due to Coronavirus / COVID-19.

Can anyone help?

**Update 2020/05/04 17:05**:

In answer to [Ramhound's comment #1](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10#comment2354133_1548480):
1. No, all user profiles are solely on the system drive (C:).
2. I downloaded and ran SetupDiag v1.6 (latest) from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag → https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870142 which reported the following:

```
Matching Profile found: OptionalComponentOpenPackageFailed - 22952520-EC89-4FBD-94E0-B67DF88347F6
SetupDiag version: 1.6.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = [REDACTED]
    Manufacturer = FUJITSU
    Model = ESPRIMO E410
    HostOSArchitecture = 2057
    FirmwareType = PCAT
    BiosReleaseDate = 20150422000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = BIOS Date: 04/22/15 12:46:17 Ver: 04.06.05
    BiosVersion = V4.6.5.3 R1.30.0 for D3120-A1x
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.16299
    HostOSBuildString = 16299.431.amd64fre.rs3_release_svc_escrow.180502-1908
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.17134.1 (rs4_release.180410-1804)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = Webroot SecureAnywhere
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 04/05/2020 10:47:29
    UpgradeEndTime = 04/05/2020 12:30:10
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 01:42:41
    CV = xaR0eqEoHEKd2Og6
    ReportId = 


Error: SetupDiag reports Optional Component installation failed to open OC Package.
Last Phase: Safe OS 
Last Operation: Gather Optional Component status
Package Name: Foundation
Error: 0x8007001F

Refer to "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness" for possible remediation information.
Recommend you check the "Windows Modules Installer" service (Trusted Installer) is started on the system and set to automatic start, reboot and try the update again.  Optionally, you can check the status of optional components on the system (search for Windows Features), uninstall any unneeded optional components, reboot and try the update again.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Safe OS
    Phase Started: 04/05/2020 12:30:01
    Phase Ended: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Gather Optional Component status
    Operation Started: 04/05/2020 12:30:02
    Operation Ended: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

Interestingly, I opened `appwiz.cpl` → `Turn Windows features on or off` to see what optional components are instaled and it simply doesn't load anything:

[image]

This led me to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness so I ran the following PowerShell commands:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\Windows10v1909\sources\boot.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\Users\$Env:userName\Desktop\Mount

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Mounting image
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\Users\$Env:userName\Desktop\Mount\windows /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

The upgrade to v1909 failed in the same way, though.

In answer to [Ramhound's comment #2](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10#comment2354133_1548480): I'm unsure how I didn't happen across [that post](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803) during my research but, in any case, I used my file `Windows_10_EnglishUK_1803_April2018Update_64bit.iso` to attempt a direct-path upgrade which failed in the same way:

[image]

In answer to [John's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10#comment2354140_1548480): I tried using `MediaCreationTool1909.exe` → `Upgrade this PC now` but that failed in the same way.

In answer to [JW0914's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10#comment2354175_1548480):
1. The file `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` has the following new entries in it (there were actually ~48 of the lines `App1:` but I couldn't fit them all in):

```
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to find a matching version for servicing stack: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.428_none_1704c21831ffb4a8\ [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to find servicing stack directory in online store. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v10.0.16299.428 with Core: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.428_none_1704c21831ffb4a8\cbscore.dll
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to create open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_1653900665 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to create open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:50:42, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
2020-05-04 15:50:45, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:Dynamic Update, UpdateID:{33D6CF13-224E-459B-AD4F-AF8C5E3CC469}, revision: 202
2020-05-04 15:50:45, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_1685496589 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:50:46, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:Dynamic Update, UpdateID:{CAEF987D-2E08-49D8-8C68-5D6FA9F801E2}, revision: 200
2020-05-04 15:50:46, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_1690150083 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:50:46, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB4497165~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4.1, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, RevisionComp: EQ, Exist: present
2020-05-04 15:50:46, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent (exact match): Parent: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.18362.1, parent state: Absent
2020-05-04 15:50:46, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_KB4497165~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4.1, applicable state: Absent
2020-05-04 15:52:19, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_2621054062 initialized by client Setup360, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:52:20, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_2633102031 initialized by client OCLib, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:52:20, Info                  CBS    Not able to find an installed package package from moniker: @Foundation [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:52:20, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve package from moniker [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:52:20, Info                  CBS    Failed to create open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:52:20, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
2020-05-04 15:53:00, Info                  CBS    Session: 30810659_3031483361 initialized by client WinMgmt, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2020-05-04 15:53:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to find an installed package package from moniker: @Foundation [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:53:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve package from moniker [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:53:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to create open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2020-05-04 15:53:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: ExecutionEngineFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Ending the TiWorker main loop.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker finalization.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: ManifestCacheFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: ExecutionEngineFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CBS Engine already deativated
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CBS Engine already deativated
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: ComponentAnalyzerFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: PackageTrackerFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CoreResourcesUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: SessionManagerFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CapabilityManagerFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: PublicObjectMonitorFinalize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: Enter vCoreInitializeLock
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: WcpUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: DrupUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CfgMgr32Unload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: DpxUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: SrUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CbsEsdUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CbsTraceInfoUninitialize
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: CbsEventUnregister
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: AppContainerUnload
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: WdsUnload, logging from cbscore will end.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker finalization.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2020-05-04 15:55:00, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
```

The recommendations for fixing error `0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE` seems to be resetting Windows Update components which I've already tried.

2. I ran the commands (output below - I'm unsure what's up with that 20 %) and tried again but the upgrade failed in the same way.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

[===========                20.0%                          ]
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> SFC /ScanNow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In answer to [Ramhound's comment #3](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10#comment2354213_1548480): To determine whether KB3022345 was installed, I tried:

- Running CMD command `wmic qfe list brief /format:texttablewsys | find "KB3022345"` but it reported `No Instance(s) Available.`
- Running PowerShell command `Get-Hotfix` but it outputted absolutely nothing.
- Running CMD command  `systeminfo.exe` but it outputted `Hotfix(s): N/A`, among everything else.
- Using `regedit.exe` to search all keys, values, and data for `KB3022345` but nothing was found.
- As per https://www.sysnative.com/forums/threads/windows-seven-cant-update.30365/post-286650, running administrative CMD command `reg load HKLM\COMPONENTS C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\COMPONENTS` which completed successfully then using [Farbar Recovery Scan Tool](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039025013-Run-Farbar-Recovery-Scan-Tool-to-gather-logs) 64-bit version 03-05-2020 (latest) to search the registry for `KB3022345` which outputted the following:

  ```
  Farbar Recovery Scan Tool (x64) Version: 03-05-2020
  Ran by <username> (04-05-2020 16:50:19)
  Running from C:\Users\<username>\Desktop
  Boot Mode: Normal

  ================== Search Registry: "KB3022345" ===========


  ====== End of Search ======
  ```

**Update 2020/05/07 15:52:**

In answer to [JW0914's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2354425_1548480): I mounted my file `Windows_10_EnglishUK_1909_November2019Update_64bit.iso` and ran the recommended commands which outputted the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> DISM /Get-WIMinfo /WIMfile:D:\sources\install.esd

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Details for image : D:\sources\install.esd

Index : 1
Name : Windows 10 S
Description : Windows 10 S
Size : 15,717,444,845 bytes

Index : 2
Name : Windows 10 S N
Description : Windows 10 S N
Size : 14,651,579,555 bytes

Index : 3
Name : Windows 10 Home
Description : Windows 10 Home
Size : 15,528,886,602 bytes

Index : 4
Name : Windows 10 Home N
Description : Windows 10 Home N
Size : 14,465,481,381 bytes

Index : 5
Name : Windows 10 Home Single Language
Description : Windows 10 Home Single Language
Size : 15,531,153,450 bytes

Index : 6
Name : Windows 10 Education
Description : Windows 10 Education
Size : 15,719,400,830 bytes

Index : 7
Name : Windows 10 Education N
Description : Windows 10 Education N
Size : 14,648,998,694 bytes

Index : 8
Name : Windows 10 Pro
Description : Windows 10 Pro
Size : 15,719,526,598 bytes

Index : 9
Name : Windows 10 Pro N
Description : Windows 10 Pro N
Size : 14,649,755,740 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:D:\sources\install.esd:8 /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.431

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

The upgrade to v1909 failed in the same way again.

In answer to [Ramhound's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1548480/safe-os-replicate-oc-errors-upgrading-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment2354337_1548480): I found that Webroot SecureAnywhere:

1. Is not listed in `appwiz.cpl`.
2. Cannot be uninstalled via administrative command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Webroot\WRSA.exe" -uninstall` because all it does is cause a wordless warning window to prompt asking yes or no and neither option works.
3. Is not detected by Revo Uninstaller.
4. Cannot be repaired (installed over) using http://anywhere.webrootcloudav.com/zerol/wsainstall.exe, https://anywhere.webrootcloudav.com/zerol/wsasme.exe, or https://anywhere.webrootcloudav.com/zerol/wsasme.msi as the EXEs simply cause the UI to open and the MSI did fix the `appwiz.cpl` listing but nothing else.

I think I'm just going to have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Not an answer, but this is a great question. It shows you've put the effort in already, and you're genuinely stuck. Kudos for that!

Comment: Is your user profile on another drive other then the system drive?   I would attempt to update to 1803 instead.  I would also try using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors) to diagnose the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Windows 10 version 1511 won't update to latest 1803?](https://superuser.com/questions/1408021/my-windows-10-version-1511-wont-update-to-latest-1803)

Comment: Try the Media Creation link and do a Repair Install. It may be the same as what you did, or possibly there is something about this system that is different.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10   .  Use the second link in the MCL and try running in place.

Comment: Your [issue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolution-procedures#other-error-codes) could be a myriad of things and the [install logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files#analyze-log-files) should tell you exactly what the issue is.  It could also be a dirty Component Store, resolve via `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > `SFC /ScanNow` > Retry install.  _(**run commands in order listed**; `DISM` should always be run before `SFC`, else `SFC` is a waste of time)_

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1519491/unable-to-update-windows-7-to-windows-10

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated my question with responses to your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @John I've updated my question with responses to your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @JW0914 I've updated my question with responses to your comments. Thanks.

Comment: At this point, back up the computer (data, documents and files) and then re-install Windows fresh. That is about all that is left now.

Comment: @mythofechelon - I would temporarily get rid of *Webroot SecureAnywhere*

Comment: @mythofechelon If the log you posted is from after the `DISM` sequence and a try of the install, the log file shows the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] is corrupted, else it's dirty _(missing hard links or hard links are missing files they're hard-linked to)_.  At this point, troubleshooting this further will likely take more time than it would to clean install and re-install all programs, and even after troubleshooting, the update may still fail due to Component Store corruption.

Comment: @mythofechelon When trying to `/RestoreHealth` via a WIM source, the `sources\boot.wim` is the wrong one to use (`sources\install.wim` || `sources\install.esd`), and it must be from the same version of Win10 installed [v1709], else it may not replace the corrupted `.cab`'s or may replace them with wrong versions, further corrupting the Component Store. First, get the index of the Win10 Pro image via `DISM /Get-WIMinfo /WIMfile:Z:\sources\install.wim` then `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:Z:\sources\install.wim:6 /LimitAccess` _(where `6` is the index #)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually flattened the installation of Windows 10 v1709 and installed Windows 10 v1909 with no issues at all.

Comment: This is one for the history books, no doubt... :-) "Out with the old, in with the new" has always been the Microsoft equivalent of Intel's "Let the chips fall where they may", anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue month ago due to end point security.  Check you software Installations. endpoint protection or Security software blocking changes to system drivers. Remove it and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue while upgrading Windows 7 to 10 through local extracted ISO file placed on network. It turned out to be some missing drivers on intel chip-set. Install all drivers and error will disappear.